# How to execute javascript on a URL programmatically

Tags: javascript

I would like to use Readability's javascript to clean up news articles, then download the generated article. What this entails is being able to execute their js code:

```
window.baseUrl          = 'https://www.readability.com';
window.readabilityToken = '';

var s = document.createElement('script');

s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
s.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');
s.setAttribute('src', baseUrl + '/bookmarklet/read.js');

document.documentElement.appendChild(s);
```

in an environment different from a traditional web browser. For example, this is possible to do by executing the above code on a site using Firebug; I would like to emulate that functionality through Java (without a browser).  One of the problems I see here is the "window" object, which may not be present when accessing pages programmatically.

Any hints on whether this is possible and how to implement?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at a headless browser, such as [EnvJS](http://www.envjs.com).